# Filter Table based on Radio selected id from the Query

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to filter the table list based on the selected query status. If the query status id lets say 1, the table must be visible and it must show only rows of query where the column query status id 1.

I do not know how to go about filtering inside the query object.

Here is snippet of my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wbg67u?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

(note: I'm not very familiar with Angular, so there may be some Angular-specific rules that I'm breaking here).

Your `query` is an array of objects, so we use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter to just the ones that we want.  The `id` property is a string (like `"1"`) on the queries, but a `number` on the options, so you do need to convert one of them in order to compare.  My first pass at a filtered query is

```
this.query.filter(q => parseInt(q.queryStatus.id) === this.radioSelected)
```

But if nothing is checked then this will return no queries, when we want it to return all queries.  So we need to see if there is a selection or not.

```
if (this.radioSelected === undefined) {
   return this.query;
} else {
   return this.query.filter(q => parseInt(q.queryStatus.id) === this.radioSelected)
}
```

I've changed the typescript type `radioSelected: any;` to `radioSelected: number | undefined;` (you should avoid using `any` whenever possible).  Also, you were storing `queryStatus.denomination` to `radioSelected`, but it makes more sense to store `queryStatus.id` so I changes that in the html.  Especially in this case where you have inconsistent spaces around your strings, a number comparison is less error-prone than a string comparison.

Lastly, we need to change the html so that it shows the filtered query rather than the original query. I don't know much about Angular so I'm not sure what the pros and cons are
of defining `filteredQuery` as a property vs a method, but I made it a method.  And then changed

```
<tr *ngFor="let queryDetails of query">
```

to

```
<tr *ngFor="let queryDetails of filteredQuery()">
```

and [it works as expected](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ffuuiw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Thank you, Linda. The solution works perfectly.  I am thinking which logic to use should I want the first radio button to be checked by default then filter instead of load all the query data. Thought it could be more user friendly that way.